# Sum the value of range column

Tags: python

```
tuition = 10966
increase_rate = 0.062

# print headings
print("Year #\t\tProjected Annual Tuition")
print("----------------------------------------")
for y in range(1, 5):
    tuition_inc = tuition*increase_rate
    tuition += tuition_inc
    print(y, "\t\t$", format(tuition, ",.2f"), sep='')
```

How to sum the column of Projected Annual Tuition? When use the `sum` function it is summing the years and not the amount of all 4 years tuition combined.

Comment: You are not storing those values anywhere... How exactly are you using `sum`? You should just use a running sum in the loop... `total = 0` and then `total += tuition` inside the loop

Comment: You need to create a new variable and add the tuition for every year. Currently you are not storing the net tuition anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Try first defining the total first outside of the loop -

```
total = 0
```

And then inside the loop use

```
total += tuition
```

so you can actually save the total, and then have it equal the sum of all the tuition years.

Comment: Thanks! please check it so it shows as a solution :)